# Converting multiple Twitter JSON files into one single CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter

I scraped a large amount of Twitter data using the Twitter API.
Now that I stored the JSON files on my computer, I want to combine them (approx. 1000 files) into a single csv file for further processing.

Each JSON file looks like this:

```js
200
{
    "data": [
        {
            "author_id": "34571035",
            "created_at": "2019-12-29T20:02:19.000Z",
            "id": "1211376921407369216",
            "text": "RT @ConnectedCarMag: Free online magazine for connected, autonomous and electric car professionals. Sign up 4 Connected Car mag #ConnectedC\u2026"
        },
        {
            "author_id": "5946022",
            "created_at": "2019-12-29T19:04:28.000Z",
            "id": "1211362363351261184",
            "text": "..."
        }, 
            ...
```

I tried so many different codes to convert the JSON files into a single csv, but as I try to use any given code I get either one of the Error Codes:

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 4)
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
ValueError: Trailing data

When I use pandas to convert the files into csv, I already encounter a problem when using pd.read_json(). Even though I tried setting lines=True, I was not able to even enter the JSON files as a Dataframe in Python.

I am very new to Python and programming overall, therefore any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid, the `200` should not be at the beginning. I'd modify the script that is writing that part.
You can di it in pandas if you `pd.read_json(<json_variable_name>['data'])` but the easiest way to do it would be using the function below:

```py
import json
import csv
from typing import Dict, List, Union

# standard function I use for reading json files
def read_json(path: str) -> Union[Dict, List]:
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

# standard function I use for writing list of dicts to csv
def write_csv(data: List[Dict], path: str) -> None:
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        fields = set().union(*data)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

json_data = read_json('your_file.json')

# write the json data (dictionary) to a csv
write_csv(json_data['data'], 'data.csv')
```

Note the use of `json_data['data']` the `['data']` part accesses the `"data"` key's values of the json response

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! However, when I use the function I get the error "NameError: name 'Union' is not defined". Do I need to change the "-> Union[Dict, List]:" part?

Comment: Whoops, looks like I forgot an import, should be fine now. Those are just type annotations, they don't make the code act any differently but they do make things easier to debug depending on what IDE you use